# How to stop truncation of strings at 255

Tags: sas, spss

I have problems exporting long string variables from SAS to SPSS.

```
DATA testString;
INPUT testString $ 300.;
testLength=LENGTH(testString);
DATALINES;
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
;
RUN;

PROC EXPORT
DATA=WORK.teststring
FILE="H:/TestSPSStrucation.sav"
DBMS=SAV
REPLACE;
```

When I open the exported SPSS file, the string is truncated at 255 characters. I have tried different things like changing the dbms to SPSS or mixing the formats. Without much result.

The SPSS file that is generated, testString variable is type String and has Width 765. There is no issue adding characters to the variable to get a wider string than 255 characters.

Comment: Looks like some versions of SPSS had a 255 character limit. Would check your SPSS  first. It's possible the export engine doesn't support longer strings when writing to SPSS.

Comment: SPSS has no problem with strings longer than 255 characters. I can edit the generated file and add a few characters to get above 255 characters without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of SAS 9.4, according to the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003103775.htm), SAS supports a maximum of 256 bytes (characters) for character variables when exporting to SPSS.  My guess would be that this was a limitation of an older SPSS version that was current when SAS developed the SPSS export engine.

SPSS is capable of importing directly from a SAS dataset (a .sas7bdat), and that may be the better way to get around this.

Comment: That might be the anwer but does limit the functionality I want. That is exporting datasets with variable and value labels directly to an SPSS file and hand it over to the researcher in question.

Comment: I would post a suggestion on communities.sas.com then.  Another option would be to write out a text file and an SPSS import script from SAS; that's a common way to do these interchanges.  I looked briefly to see if R could help you, but it looks like `write.foreign(package=SPSS)` is as bad or worse than SAS's export.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this by expanding the character variable padding (CVP) engine. Try a libname statement with the option CVPBYTES = #bytes you need?

Comment: Could you give a program how to apply this in my sample case?

Comment: Not a program I think you need to change your libname statement before you import libname expand 'SAS data-library' cvpmultiplier=2.5; or whatever the number of bytes are. I've not worked with SPSS data but I remember one of my friends imported a data set that he hhad to increase the cvpBYTES but the doccumentation I looked up makes me think the CVPmultiplier may be w hat you need

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this could help here.  Character variable padding is needed when you have issues with unicode or DBCS encoding, but I don't think SPSS handles that any differently than SAS.

Answer (score 0):

SPSS has supported string variables up to 32K in length for quite a while now.  You might try using the SPSS procedure to read the SAS file directory.  File > Open or, in syntax, GET TRANSLATE.